# Is it possible to obtain an access_token with expo-auth-session/providers/google?

Tags: firebase, expo, access-token

I am trying to obtain an access token for use with Google APIs using the up-to-date expo-auth-session package.

It works fine to fetch an id_token via `useAuthRequest({responseType: "id_token", ...})` or `useIdTokenAuthRequest({...})`

However, when trying `useAuthRequest({responseType: "code", ...})`, I get the following error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value (other than grant type), repeats a parameter, includes multiple credentials, utilizes more than one mechanism for authenticating the client, or is otherwise malformed.]

Does anyone know what is missing from the request? I am using the Expo Go app currently, so I'm not sure if that prevents obtaining an access token. Currently digging through the package's source code...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two props to `useAuthRequest`

```
shouldAutoExchangeCode: false,
clientSecret: 'any_bogus_value!'
```

`shouldAutoExchangeCode` will prevent the code from being exchanged and send it back to you in the response.

`clientSecret` will simply trigger and if check to be true in the providers source code that will avoid that error you specified being returned.

Note that in general it is not a good practice to avoid errors, but in this case, I feel like the error is being shown in error itself!

Comment: Thank you for your answer -- I now get the following when including the values above (among others):

[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).]

Please note I am looking for access_token and not authorization code

Comment: Then you can use responseType: token